# « il n’avait pas l’air d'être un rival » or « il n’a pas l’air d'avoir été un rival »

Tags: temps-grammatical

> Person A: Il a cru qu'il allait faire fortune. Mais en fin de compte, son commerce s’est effondré.
>
> Person B: C'est plutôt bon pour vous. Encore qu'il n’**avait** pas l’air d'**être** un rival dangereux.
>
> {or} Person B: C'est plutôt bon pour vous. Encore qu'il n’**a** pas l’air d'**avoir été** un rival dangereux.

I’m trying to translate the English sentence below into French, and not sure of the tense to use for the « l’air » part.

The context is that the company run by Person A’s old business rival went bankrupt and Person A doesn’t know where he is now.

Person B is forming an opinion about Person A’s old rival, based only on what she has just heard from Person A.

> Person B: Though, from what you’ve told me, **it doesn’t seem like he was much of a rival to you**, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is about using the past indication on *avoir l'air de* and present indication on *être un rival dangereux*, or the contrary.

I prefer the first one (*avait l'air d'être*) because you don't know where he is now, so you remember what he looked like in those days you are talking about.

> De quoi avait-il l'air, à cette époque ?
>
> Pas d'(être) un rival dangereux, en tout cas.

I'd use the second one if the guy is in front of me now and I can tell by his look that he probably wasn't a rival in those days. But maybe someone will tell you that nowadays he looks inoffensive, but it wasn't the case at that time.

> De quoi a-t-il l'air, aujourd'hui ?
>
> Pas d'avoir été un rival dangereux, en tout cas.

Answer (score 2):

I would translate this:

Person B: Though, from what you’ve told me, it doesn’t seem like he was much of a rival to you, anyway.

like this:

Personne B: Quoique, d'après ce que vous m'avez dit, il ne semblait pas être un rival important pour vous, de toute façon.

Hope this will help!

Comment: Hi. My question is not about how to translate the sentence, but rather about what tense to use for the "l'air" part {of the two possible choices I highlighted}. So please stick to the expression "avoir l'air de". Merci.